# Rate constant units for gravimetric measurements

Tags: kinetics

For gravimetric measurements, why is the reaction rate constant $k$ represented change in mass per time?

> #### Evaporation Rate and Activation Energy
>
> Evaporation changed the slag chemical composition and as a result affected the evaporation rate in the process of measurements. To mitigate this effect, the evaporation rates were analyzed in the first 10 minutes of the TGA measurements. Evaporation rate $k$, $\pu{s^{-1}}$, was calculated as:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> k &= - \frac{\Delta m_i / m_0}{t_i} \\
> \Delta m_i &= m_i - m_0
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> where $\Delta m_i / m_0$ is the flux mass change, and $m_i$, $\pu{g}$, is the flux mass at time $t_i$, $\pu{s}$.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. In the future, please don't paste images; [reformat](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) mathematical expressions and equations using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: I guess that this is merely convenient. You can go through the motions of converting it to moles, but that would not yield a more meaningful result. Given the application (thermo-gravimetric analysis), a rate in terms of mass is probably the most useful.